# “svn upgrade” on old working copy fails with “E235000: Unable to upgrade” — How to troubleshoot?

Tags: svn

I’m dusting off some old work that I haven’t touched since about 2010, including a few old svn repo working copies.  Trying `svn status` (or other common svn commands) fails with the error

```
   svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command”
   svn: E155036: The working copy at '/Users/pll/backups/2010/My Old Repository'
is too old (format 10) to work with client version '1.14.2 (r1899510)' (expects format 31). You need to upgrade the working copy first.
```

On the first repo I tried, `svn upgrade` worked fine, and I was able to convert it to git as hoped.  On the other repos, `svn upgrade` fails with error

```
svn: E235000: Unable to upgrade '/Users/pll/backups/2010/My Old Repository' at line 1817
```

**How can I troubleshoot this further?**  Even for the nuclear option of a fresh checkout, I would need to find the repo’s original url (and hope it’s still live) — but `svn info` fails with the original error `svn: E155036: Please see the 'svn upgrade' command`, and all other commands I’ve tried similarly demand upgrading the working copy first.

In case it’s relevant, the “line 1817” in the “unable to upgrade” error is the *same* line number in the 3 different repos I’m having this issue with — they’re independent repositories with no common content.  My `svn` is version 1.14.2, installed with homebrew.

*Edit:* @thebjorn suggests installing an older svn client. Unfortunately, I can’t find any way to install an old enough version to work with the old format directly — I’m on Mac OS 12.5.1, and according to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/272686), installing svn ≤1.7 is both very difficult and (if possible) highly discouraged due to security issues.  (And the “very difficult” is borne out by the rest of my searching — I haven’t found any plausible install method at all.)  I’ve tried installing v1.8; this gives almost exactly the same errors as v1.14, except that the line number changes to 1740.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried downloading an older svn client..?

Comment: @thebjorn: Thanks for the suggestion — somehow I hadn’t thought of that!  Unfortunately now I tried it, but without any progress — will update the question with details.  tl;dr: I can’t find a way to install versions <1.8, and v1.8 gives almost exactly the same errors I originally got.